# C# DLL Function With Changing Parameters

Tags: c#, dll

I am working with a C# DLL.  One of the functions in that DLL used to have 2 parameters, and recently changed to 4 parameters.

I am looking for a way for my program to support both versions.

My issue is I haven't found a way because the linker requires that I match the function signature that is available.

Comment: Are the two new parameters optional ?

Comment: make yourself a wrapper around the function (facade) and use this instead of the direct call ... maybe the function will have 8 parameters next :(

Comment: if i'm not mistaken you can use a PInvoke call to check if a method exists.. what that PInvoke call is I can't remember off the top of my head

Comment: C# doesn't use a linker, this problem is caught by the compiler.  It can tell your code isn't ever going to work.  If you can't convince the library owner to keep his code compatible and still provide both overloads then you'll have to maintain two versions of your program.

Comment: The parameters aren't optional.  I think my workaround will be just to update to the latest version, and work with the owner of the DLL so they don't change the public interface in the future.  Unfortunately I don't have complete control over that.  I was just hoping there was some C# magic that I didn't know about.

Comment: Also, C# does have a linker. It is combined with the compiler as one step, but the step of linking is still required.